# Rails AJAX create post not Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My ajax request seems to be working fine. A console.log is coming out, status is 200, and params are saving in the DB. Something is wrong with the way I am rendering my form on the index page (home_controller) or something like that or some stupid HTML error. Been looking at it forever and can't decipher it.

Here's where I am displaying the posts *views/home/index.html.erb*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
        <%= link_to new_post_path, remote: true do %>
            <button class="btn btn-default">+New Post</button>
        <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" id="post-form" style="display:none;">
     </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" id="all-posts">
      <%= render @posts %>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my *views/posts/create.js.erb*

```
$('#all-posts').html(" <%= j (render @posts) %> ");
$('#post-form').slideUp(350);
console.log('hello')
```

here is my posts controller *controllers/posts_controller.rb*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :js

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.create(post_params)
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

this is my form to create posts *views/posts/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, remote: true do |f|   %>
  <%= f.input  :content, input_html: {class: 'form-group' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Home controller *controllers/home_controller.rb*

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey nate, when i am having trouble with this the first place i look is in the chrome developer tools in the network and console tabs.  It will show you the js that is being rendered and then you can run that line by line to help isolate the problem.  If you do that and run into trouble just add it on here and i'll check it.  Most of the time it ends up being something that is not escaped as it is sent across the wire.

Comment: Does the partial rendering in views/posts/create.js.erb have access to @posts since it's defined in a different controller than the Posts controller?

Comment: Ya know, I checked the network response thing like 20x and just realized that within the html() it is just "".

Comment: Since I declared @posts in the home controller, I thought that made it available

Comment: I switched the J (render)  line to just hello and it displays hello fine, so it's something I'm doing with the form or not escaping Javascript properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `@posts = Post.all` to the create action of your Posts controller to make it available to views/posts/create.js.erb.

I don't believe adding it to your home controller will make it available in views/posts. If you wanted something available across controllers then you would add it to your Application controller but I wouldn't do that here.

Comment: I tried that, but it's still the same thing. The stuff inside the html() is still just blank.

Comment: Did you try  moving the js file so that it's in the same directory as the index view? I'd try creating an action in the Home controller with @posts defined and put the javascript in the same controller folder as <action>.js.erb. Just thinking aloud.